# How do I make Excel user-defined function (UDF) accept arguments of String type and range type?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make a function `do_something_to_string(one_arg)` where one_arg can be of string type or be a range.

In the case of a range, I want to concatenate every cell of the range into one long string but processing. But I can't seem to make a function that can accept either a string or a Range as argument.

Comment: Why can't you make two functions ?  `do_something_to_string` & `do_something_to_range`

Comment: you can do sum(1,2,3) or sum(a1:a3). I think it's better the way I proposed.

Comment: What do you want to do in the case of the `String` argument?

Comment: Your plan for the range seems to be replicating `TEXTJOIN`, which if you don't have access to in your version of Excel, you can still find an example of a UDF that does the trick here on SO.

Comment: `doSomeThing(arg As Variant)` then check `TypeName(arg)` to see what was passed in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use optional arguments or a variant:

```
Function MyFunction1(Optional Str As String, Optional Rng As Range) As String
    Dim C As Range, S As String
    If Rng Is Nothing Then
        MyFunction1 = Str
    Else
        S = ""
        For Each C In Rng
            S = S & CStr(C.Value)
        Next
        MyFunction1 = S
    End If
End Function

Function MyFunction2(V As Variant) As String
    Dim C As Range, S As String
    If VarType(V) = vbString Then
        MyFunction2 = V
    ElseIf TypeName(V) = "Range" Then
        S = ""
        For Each C In V
            S = S & CStr(C.Value)
        Next
        MyFunction2 = S
    Else
        Err.Raise 13, , "The argument must be a String or a Range."
    End If
End Function
```

Then try:

```
Debug.Print MyFunction1("test")
Debug.Print MyFunction1(, Range("A1:B3"))
Debug.Print MyFunction2("test")
Debug.Print MyFunction2(Range("A1:B3"))
```